# Avoiding a redundant query in a join

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

The salient feature of this problem is trying to get two columns from a row without a second query returning the same row. I've included more information for context.

I have the following (simplified) tables which represent documents sent to us by customers, scanned in batches by users here.

```
          Batches: Id, ...
        Documents: Id, CustomerId, ...
Documents_Batches: Id, BatchId, DocumentId
```

And document history (Creation, state changes, edits, etc.):

```
   DocumentEvents: Id, DocumentId, UserId, Occurred (datetime)
```

What I want is list of documents in a given batch, plus some event data:

```
           Result: DocumentId, CustomerId, Created, CreatedBy, ...
```

How do I get *both* the Created date, and the CreatedBy value in that same row?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetBatchDocuments]
@BatchId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Documents.Id, 
        Documents.CustomerId, 
        MIN(DocumentEvents.Occurred) AS Created,
        /* UserId value of the 'Created' row, AS CreatedBy */
        MAX(DocumentEvents.Occurred) AS Modified
        /* UserId value of the 'Modfied' row, AS ModifiedBy */
    FROM
        Documents 
        INNER JOIN Documents_Batches        
        ON Documents.Id = Documents_Batches.DocumentId
        INNER JOIN DocumentEvents
        ON Documents.Id = DocumentEvents.DocumentId
        WHERE Documents_Batches.BatchId = @BatchId;
END
```

Although I could likely get them beforehand, or with a function call, every case I can think of would mean multiple queries of the same row.

**EDIT**: Barring some surprise idea from SO, I've concluded that this isn't logically possible without a second query to the same row (for each Date/User column pair I want). In order to make this happen, SQL would need a Row-valued (vs. a table-valued) function, and internally, that would need first filter by DocumentId, and then filter that result by the lowest/highest date. No matter the approach, it's two queries. Maybe time to reassess the normalization strategy for this data.

Comment: Is there a 1-1 mapping between `Documents and DocumentEvents` and also `Documents and Documents_Batches`, for 1 particular batch n this case ?

Comment: @SoulTrain: They are both one-to-many.

Comment: @Serpiton: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

Playing with the CTE and the ROW_NUMBER function you can do something like

```
WITH MinMax AS (
SELECT d.Id
     , d.CustomerId
     , de.Occurred
     , de.UserId
     , RowAsc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Id, d.CustomerId
                                   ORDER BY de.Occurred)
     , RowDesc =ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Id, d.CustomerId
                                   ORDER BY de.Occurred Desc)
FROM   Documents d
       INNER JOIN Documents_Batches d_b ON d.Id = d_b.DocumentId
       INNER JOIN DocumentEvents de ON d.Id = d_e.DocumentId
WHERE  d_b.BatchId = @BatchId;
)
SELECT Id, CustomerId
     , Created = Max(Case When RowAsc = 1 Then Occurred Else Null End)
     , CreatedBy = Max(Case When RowAsc = 1 Then UserId Else Null End)
     , Modified = Max(Case When RowDesc = 1 Then Occurred Else Null End)
     , ModifiedBy = Max(Case When RowDesc = 1 Then UserId Else Null End)
FROM   MinMax
WHERE  1 IN (RowAsc, RowDesc)
GROUP BY Id, CustomerId
```

In MinMax the row with RowAsc = 1 is the row with the min date and the row with RowDesc = 1 is the row with the max date for the Id, CustomerId group

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. Two joins are not redundant, they select different information.

```
SELECT 
    Documents.Id, 
    Documents.CustomerId, 

    MinTable.Created,
    MinTable.UserId AS CreatedBy,

    MaxTable.Modified,
    MaxTable.UserId AS ModifiedBy
FROM
    Documents 
    INNER JOIN Documents_Batches        
    ON Documents.Id = Documents_Batches.DocumentId

    INNER JOIN (SELECT Occurred AS Created, UserId, DocumentId FROM DocumentEvents GROUP BY DocumentId, CustomerId HAVING Occurred = MIN(Occurred)) AS MinTable
    ON Documents.Id = MinTable.DocumentId

    INNER JOIN (SELECT Occurred AS Modified, UserId, DocumentId FROM DocumentEvents GROUP BY DocumentId, CustomerId HAVING Occurred = MAX(Occurred)) AS MaxTable
    ON Documents.Id = MaxTable.DocumentId

    WHERE Documents_Batches.BatchId = @BatchId;
```

Comment: I think I understand this, but it does not define the DocumentId column for MinTable or MaxTable; when I define it, I get an error: Column 'DocumentEvents.DocumentId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. My TSQL is pretty rudimentary, so I will need to look up these points.

Comment: I've edited the answer, now you shouldn't get that error. Just added DocumentId to the sub selects.

Comment: Your edit is what I did; that's what throws the error.

Comment: oh of course, it needs to be grouped by document id. Try again please.

Comment: Fixed, but got the same error regarding CustomerId; I added ", CustomerId" to each after the GROUP clause, and it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, actually it just appeared to be working; the UserId values it returns are not always correct, because it's just taking the top of the group.

Comment: I think I'm done pasting code to see if it runs without an error. Thanks for your effort, I got some insight from it.

Comment: You're done pasting code to see if it runs without error? Very touchy programmer you are.